# What is the term for intended consequences of an activity other than intended learning outcomes?

Tags: teaching, learning

Question might be a bit strange.  I am looking at a series of activities that we run every year.  These activities have some intended learning outcomes (ILOs), but these outcomes are stated in terms of what students will know or be able to do at the end.  I'm trying to explain not just the ILOs but rather the intended experience that the students will have.  For example:

"Students will keep up with their homework and review course material throughout the semester, rather than cramming during exam times"

This isn't really an ILO, but it is an intended thing that students will do this due to the nature of the activity.  Is there a term for this type of thing in pedagogy? "Intended Student Experience", perhaps?

Comment: Would "Expected experiences" do?

Comment: Ignore previous comments, I think I misunderstood what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the distinction is between those intended outcomes that can be measured in some reasonable way at or soon after the end of the course and other intended consequences that can't be measured effectively. Any distinction will probably do the job, even "Other intended outcomes" or "Unmeasured intended/potential outcomes" or "Hoped-for behavioral changes".

Just make the distinction clear both in how you intend to both have students arrive at the outcomes (perhaps not the same for the two categories) and how you distinguish between the categories.

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems more like a rule or expectation rather than an objective or learning outcome. It would be difficult to measure this directly as you can only  surmise that students don't study and are cramming instead.

If you want them to study you need to embed study activities into the curriculum. For example, reviewing material in class, study guides, quizzes, chapter summaries, presentations by students, etc.are all ideas.

The general point is that constant assessment compels constant studying while giant mega exams such as midterms and final exams encourage cramming because they aren't seen as imminent for many students

Comment: I fully agree.  The specific thing I'm looking into was the assumptions that were made about these activities that led to their creation.  In this case, the particular set of activities was assumed to promote studying throughout the term rather than cramming at the end.  I'm then going to analyze whether or not that really happens.  I need a useful section heading for all of these assumptions. Perhaps...just assumptions?